# Login no funciona [Django 2.2.2]

Tags: django, login, django-models, djangorestframework, django-urls

tengo el siguiente problema:

Intengo logear con la vista del login que he implementado y no realiza ninguna función al momento de presionar el botón ingresar.

cuando inicio el proyecto, este no genera ningún error.
[image: Puesta en marcha del servidor de Django]

El código del fichero **urls.py** se encuentra de la siguiente forma:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from core import views
from registration import views as views_registration


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'registration/login.html'), name='login'),  
]
```

Dentro del fichero **settings.py** se tiene configurada una ruta de re-direccionamiento  en caso de que el usuario sea el correcto:

[image: Redireccionamiento de login en caso de usuario y contraseña correcta]

Extracto de código **settings.py** :

```py
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'registration',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'HealthyV2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Código ***login.html*** :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>{% block titulo %}Iniciar Sesión{% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- Estilos y fuentes del template  -->
    {% load static %}
    <link href="{% static 'core/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'core/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="{% static 'core/css/clean-blog.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Navegación -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Healthy Home</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          Menú
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Acceder</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#}">Registro</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Cabecera -->
    {% load static %}
    <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('{% static 'core/img/login-bg.jpg' %}')">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <div class="site-heading">
              <h1>Login</h1><br><br>
              <div class="login-container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" >
    <form action="" method="POST" login-form">{% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
         {% if form.non_field_errors %}
         <p style="color:red">Usuario o contraseña incorrectos, prueba denuevo.</p> 
         {% endif %}
        <label for="username">Usuario</label>
        <input name="username" required id="id_username" type="text" class="form-control" id="user" aria-describedby="user" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" required class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Ingresa tu Contraseña">
      </div>
      
      <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Acceder</button></center>
  </form>

</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

<!-- Inicio Login -->


    <!-- Bootstrap y Javascripts -->
    <script src="{% static 'core/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'core/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'core/js/clean-blog.min.js' %}"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Código ***views.py*** de la app **registration** :

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
```

La vista (***login.html***) que quiero utilizar se encuentra dentro de la App registration en la siguiente estructura como se ve a continuación:

[image: Estructura de proyecto]

Espero puedan ayudarme, quedo atento a sus respuestas.

Comment: cambia la importacion del view a `from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView`

Comment: @JackNavaRow con ese cambio sigue igual, no realiza nada.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes compartir el settings la parte donde se configura los templates tal vez ahí te falte configurar la ruta de templates

> A esta parte me refiero que tal vez te falte configurar en el settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

> Si en la parte de 'DIRS': [] en el setting te falta configurar esto

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates'),],
```

Comment: sigue sin funcionar. Aun al presionar el botón ingresar... no hace nada más que borrar el usuario y contraseña que ingresé.

Comment: listo entonces es un problema en la view o puede ser en el html puedes pasar el código que tienes en esos dos archivos

Comment: acabo de añadir el código de dichos archivos, sin embargo la vista se la estoy pasando desde la url por eso el fichero views lo tengo vacío.

Comment: Si esto esta bien pero aqui el problema es que en el form action no hay una accion al ejectuar  <form action="" method="POST" login-form"> para ello debes programar una accion en la view para que puedas linkear al formulario

Comment: como se puede linkear el form a una función de la views?, programaré la lógica ahora pero, me falta  linkear.

Comment: hay una seccion que tienes de url puedes agregar el siguiente codigo path('loginPost/', views_registration.nuevaFuncion), name='loginPost'), nuevaFuncion es la funcion que vas a crear y loginPost debes poner en el action del form ejemplo action="loginPost"

Answer (score 0):

Saludos te sugiero realizar de la siguiente manera:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
..
..
url(r'^$', login, {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}, name='login'),
```

en tu template(registration/**login.html**):

```
    <form action="" method="POST" class="login-form" autocomplete="off">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
         {% if form.non_field_errors %}
         <p style="color:red">Usuario o contraseña incorrectos, prueba denuevo.</p> 
         {% endif %}
        <label for="username">Usuario</label>
        <input name="username" required id="id_username" type="text" class="form-control" id="user" aria-describedby="user" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" required class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Ingresa tu Contraseña">
      </div>

      <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Acceder</button></center>
  </form>
```

**settings.py**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

Basicamente con esto debe funcionar.

**Nota.-** en tu form (login.html) tienes:

es decir tienes "login-form" que no esta bien declarado dedusco que es tu clase para lo cual seria:

```
class="login-form"
```

Espero te sirva y comentame cualquier cosa..!!

Answer (score 0):

Para deducir donde se encuentran tus archivos templates en el settings.py en la parte de hasta arriba defines ya por defecto el:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

y mas abajo en TEMPLATES, el DIRS:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Para direccionarme al lugar donde están mis templates.

En mi urls.py principal agrego los accounts:

```
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('accounts/', include('apps.registration.urls')),
```

Con esto obtengo los urls de login y logout y en settings aplico donde se dirigen después de un Login o Logout

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'#definido en mis urls de inicio path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

y nada mas realizo un html a login con los datos que utiliza el genérico:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Usuario</label>
          <input type="text" id="id_username" name="username" class="form-control"  required placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" autofocus>
    </div
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" class="form-control"  required placeholder="Ingrese Contraseña">
    </div
    <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Acceder</button>
    </div
</form>
```

Veo un error ak:

```
<form action="" method="POST" login-form">{% csrf_token %}
```

Después de login-form hay unas comillas, creo no perjudica

Y de esta manera traigo el login de Django y sin necesidad de hacerle una vista y me ha funcionado muy bien. Lo único que manejo en la apps.registration son los templates de login, cambios y reset de password, profile y de registro.

Bueno espero te de un mejor panorama de lo que estas realizando.